# Why is the windows cmd not working for me?

Tags: python

While on windows cmd I am coding

> C:/Users/Esteban Oquendo/Desktop/python myexample.py

Why I am getting an error message as

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the python.exe folder is in your system path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure python is installed at the location

> C:/Users/Esteban Oquendo/Desktop/

So, make sure python.exe file is present in the directory. If you are not sure where your python is installed. Try this is your windows command line:

> which python

You will see the python location if you have python in your system (and if the python path is set correctly). Like this!

[image]